# 30 second gap in boot process

Tags: debian, boot, graphics

I did a full upgrade on my Debian system (jessie/sid).
Unfortunately there is now a 30 second gap on the bootup and I really don't know where it comes from and where I have to look to find it.

I looked at `/var/log/dmesg` and found some lines that could be interesting. Notice the gap between `27.280227` and `56.835253`.

```
[   27.261104] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[   27.280207] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   27.280213] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   27.280216] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[   27.280218] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[   27.280220] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[   27.280223] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[   27.280225] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[   27.280227] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm)
[   27.843406] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[   56.835253] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   57.068560] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   57.615554] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   57.661815] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   57.855124] fuse init (API version 7.22)
[   58.123866] Adding 4886524k swap on /dev/mapper/encrypted-swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4886524k
[   58.327537] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   59.137990] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[   59.137996] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[   59.137998] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[   59.138000] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
```

Searching for `[drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off` points to some graphical bugs. Since I have sometimes problems with my graphiccards (switchable graphic card) this could be a reason.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Device 04cd
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52
Memory at f6400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Radeon HD 6630M
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at f7b20000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Expansion ROM at f7b00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

As I said, I have no clue where to look at and what to search for. I'm also happy for some keywords that might help.

I hope I provided the information you need. If not it would be nice if you also can tell me which command I have to execute to get the output you want, since I'm still not very familiar with the 'deeper system'.

Thank you very much,

rocco

Comment: You can't watch the console while it's booting to see where the holdup occurs? Edit the boot command line to remove "quiet" if it's there. It looks like it may be busy detecting disks. Remove any cdrom or USB sticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use systemd, it could be [Debian bug 754987 in udev](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=754987), since it involves a 30-second delay.

The consequence of this bug in my dmesg log file:

```
[   19.809738] input: HP WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input14
[   25.107974] WARNING! power/level is deprecated; use power/control instead
[   50.739902] Adding 19800076k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:19800076k FS
[   50.780205] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   51.259666] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   52.346718] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   52.469463] loop: module loaded
[   52.491077] smsc47b397: found SMSC SCH5317 (base address 0x0480, revision 1)
[   52.538276] fuse init (API version 7.23)
```

It looks similar to yours.

Comment: Yes, this was it! I changed temporarily the udev_log level to "err" and the delay disappeared. Thank you!